# How to swap Hashtable's key with Value

Tags: c#, .net, hashtable

I have solved it by following.
Since it is long, i need a better one.

//Code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Hashtable hsTbl = new Hashtable();

        hsTbl.Add(1, "Suhas");
        hsTbl.Add(2, "Madhuri");
        hsTbl.Add(3, "Om");
        List<object> keyList = new List<object>();
        List<object> ValList = new List<object>();

        Console.WriteLine("Key          Value");
        foreach (DictionaryEntry item in hsTbl)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "      " + item.Value);
            keyList.Add(item.Value);
            ValList.Add(item.Key);

        }
        hsTbl.Clear()

//Swapping          

        for (int i = 0; i < keyList.Count; i++)
        {
            hsTbl.Add(keyList[i], ValList[i]);
        }

//will display hashtable after swapping

        foreach (DictionaryEntry item in hsTbl)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "      " + item.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any other better solution?

Comment: What's the reason of usage `HashTable` instead of generic `Dictionary`?

Comment: Simply create a new list with key as value and value as key in a foreach loop and forgot the old. Is swap really needed?

Comment: Do you need to consider the scenario whereby a specific key's value may be the same as another value in the same collection? Also, you may want to consider using a Dictionary for type safety and performance

Comment: No reason behind that. Just to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it slightly simpler using an additional array and the CopyTo method rather than 2 lists but without creating an additional HashTable as follows:

//Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
      Hashtable hsTbl = new Hashtable();

      hsTbl.Add(1, "Suhas");
      hsTbl.Add(2, "Madhuri");
      hsTbl.Add(3, "Om"); 

      DictionaryEntry[] entries = new DictionaryEntry[hsTbl.Count];
      hsTbl.CopyTo(entries, 0);
      hsTbl.Clear();

      foreach(DictionaryEntry de in entries) hsTbl.Add(de.Value, de.Key);

      // check it worked

      foreach(DictionaryEntry de in hsTbl)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", de.Key, de.Value);
      }
  }
}
```

Note that, in general, no method is guaranteed to work because some of the values in the original hashtable may be duplicated and therefore be unsuitable as keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generic `Dictionary<string,int>`, which is easy to create with Linq:

```
var dictionary = hsTbl.OfType<DictionaryEntry>()
                      .ToDictionary(e => (string)e.Value, e => (int)e.Key);
```

If you really need `Hashtable`, then:

```
Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in hsTbl)
    table.Add(entry.Value, entry.Key);
```

But make sure that all values are unique, if you want to swap value and key.